# MySQL Hit Counter increments by 1 or 2 depending on browser

Tags: php, mysql, hitcounter

I'm implementing a MySQL hit counter by using the following syntax

```
UPDATE table
SET Views = Views+1
WHERE ID = tableid
LIMIT 1;
```

There are two cases in which this call is being made: Once from an ajax-call (works as expected, always increments by one), and once directly from a full-page load (increases by 2 instead of 1 in, e.g., Firefox but always by 1 in, e.g., Opera). I.e., my problem ist browser/environment dependent and seems to be related to the extra stuff that exists in the full-page load.

Solution suggestions I found included empty `src` or `href` attributes triggering an extra background page-call in some browsers. Such do however not seem to exist in my case, although there are some links to page-anchors in the form `<a href="#anchor">` on the page. I tried removing these but it didn't seem to have an effect on the hit counter.

Any other ideas as to why the counter increments by two / the page is loaded twice in, e.g., Firefox and how to solve my problem?

Comment: Set a `$_SESSION` variable when the hit counter is called. When the hit counter is triggered for the second time check if the `$_SESSION` variable exists and if it does, don't increment but unset the `$_SESSION` variable instead. Unset `$_SESSION` variable as well if on any other project page. This will prevent increments by 2 in some browsers and work as a one-time reload-blocker in others where it regularly increments by 1. This work-around is somewhat unsatisfying but not a huge problem since in my case the pages will generally not be called twice consecutively.